# How to use CURDATE() and INTERVAL in Drupal Database object syntax

Tags: nodes

How to convert SQL query to Drupal Database object query. I have already tried many ways but I didn't get success.

```
# Get the records which are published in week
SELECT node.nid as nid 
FROM node node
INNER JOIN field_date field_date ON node.nid = field_date.entity_id
WHERE from_unixtime(field_date.field_date_value) BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND CURDATE();
```

The above query is working fine in mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `db_query()` function:
Solution -1

```
$query = 'SELECT node.nid as nid FROM node node INNER JOIN field_date field_date ON node.nid = field_date.entity_id WHERE from_unixtime(field_date.field_date_value) BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND CURDATE()';
$result = db_query($query)->fetchAll();
```

Solution-2

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->fields('n', array());
$query->innerJoin('field_date', 'fd', 'n.nid = fd.entity_id');
$query->where('FROM_UNIXTIME(fd.field_date_value) BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND CURDATE()');
$result = $query->execute();
```

Comment: That's for expressions (fields for the SELECT), you probably meant [`where()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3Awhere/7.x) (and you probably meant to add some fields `->fields('n', ['nid'])`)...

Comment: Yes, I was wrong. I have updated code. We can use db_query();